# Generating alarm at specific day each week at a specified time android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to trigger an alarm at 08:45 am on every monday.

```
Calendar cl1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cl1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
cl1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
cl1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
cl1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long tme = cl1.getTimeInMillis();
Intent intent = newIntent(Mondayentry.this,Alarmreceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Mondayentry.this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager al = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
al.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tme,7*1440*60000, pendingintent);
```

And I have used the following broadcast class

```
public class Alarmreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have also added in the manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".Alarmreceiver"> </receiver>
```

There is no error but the alarm is not triggered at all.
Please help me.

Comment: which version of sdk you use for test it.

Comment: I am using a VD with API-21 and my project API is 8.

Comment: Now its working. Thanks Md Abdul Gaufur for showing interest.:)

Comment: But its working only for current week and not for next week.